# opening and closing a text file many times and read from the continuation

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

I have a text file, and I open it and read one line of it, and close the text file. I'm calling my function under a for loop, but each time this function reads the first line of a text file, how can I fix it to read from the continuation

Comment: You have tagged this with `fseek`, so apparently you know about `fseek`. What problem do you have using `fseek`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're reopening the file each trip through the loop?  The more normal way of arranging things, of course, is to open the file outside/before the loop, and then you naturally read through the file sequentially.

Comment: I tagged fseek() because I heard it can help in this case but unfortunately i don't know how to use it

Comment: You can learn about `ftell` and `fseek` in [this course notes chapter](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx2i.html).

Comment: _"and I open it and read one line of it, and close the text file. I'm calling my function under a for loop, but each time this function reads the first line of a text file,"_  Okay, you've described the code.  Now, show the code so the error can be identified.    [mcve]

Comment: @ryyker: The question is not about a problem in a code. It is not a debugging question, and a minimal reproducible example is not required. OP has **working** code that opens the file and reads text. They are asking for help using `fseek`, which is not in their code. That is a request for knowledge, not a request for debugging. Alternately, they should likely be guided to not opening and closing the file repeatedly, but that is also not a question about debugging; it would be information about proper technique.

Comment: Why is anyone even suggesting `fseek`?  That is completely the wrong approach.  Just stop closing the file.  If you open it once, subsequent reads will continue from the point you last read.  Open the file once and read through it in the loop.  If you `fseek`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Re “Why is anyone even suggesting `fseek`?”: Because OP tagged it and because the question explicitly asks how to continue reading from where the program left off while it is repeatedly closing and opening the file. It is likely OP should not be repeatedly opening and closing the file, but they have agency, and it would be disrespectful to ignore their request and not provide them the information they requested. You can advise them on a better approach, but that is not a reason to withhold the information they requested, and they might have some reason for what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `fseek` to reposition yourself in the file after closing and reopening, but it is very unusual to do so.  So unusual, in fact, that I would suggest it is completely wrong.  Here's some sample code that demonstrates how to do that, as well as a more typical loop.  Each loop here reads the first 2 lines of the file, assuming each line is sufficiently small; handling long lines is beyond the scope of this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
void xfseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence, const char *);
long xftell(FILE *stream, const char *);
void xfclose(FILE *stream, const char *);


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "input";

    /* Read the first two lines of the file, closing the file on each
     * iteration. This is ** not ** the usual way to do this, and is
     * included here for demonstration
     * purposes only.  DO NOT DO THIS.
     * It is very unusual to close and re-open the file on each iteration.
     */
    long position = 0;
    for( int line = 1; line < 3; line++ ){
        FILE *ifp = xfopen(path, "r");
        char buf[1024];
        xfseek(ifp, position, SEEK_SET, path);
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ifp);  /* (1) */
        printf("line %d: %s", line, buf);
        position = xftell(ifp, path);
        xfclose(ifp, path);  /* !! */
    }

    /* The more usual way to read each line of a file is to simply
     * read it with repeated calls to the appropriate read method
     * (fgets, fread, fgetc, etc.)  Each subsequent read starts
     * where the previous read finished.
     */
    FILE *ifp = xfopen(path, "r");
    for( int line = 1; line < 3; line++ ){
        char buf[1024];
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ifp);  /* (1) */
        printf("line %d: %s", line, buf);
    }
    xfclose(ifp, path);
    return 0;
}



FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}


void
xfseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence, const char *name)
{
    if( fseek(stream, offset, whence) == -1){
        perror(name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

long
xftell(FILE *stream, const char *name)
{
    long ret = ftell(stream);
    if( ret == -1 ){
        perror(name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ret;
}

void
xfclose(FILE *stream, const char *name)
{
    if( fclose(stream) ){
        perror(name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Notes: (1) It is left as an exercise for the reader how best to handle short reads (eg, when fgets returns NULL) or long lines (eg, when fgets completely fills the buffer but fails to read an entire line).  Perhaps it is a bit of a cop-out to leave that as an exercise, but the annoyance of dealing with those issues points strongly towards reasons for using the standard idiom.  If you want to print the first two lines of the file, use some variation of `for( int count = 0; (c = fgetc(fp)) != NULL && count < 2;  ) { if( c == '\n' ) count += 1; putchar(c); }`. Putting the read function as a condition of the loop is (almost) always the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have already made suggestions on other alternatives for what you are attempting.  But regardless whether it is the right approach or not, it seems pretty clear that your stated ask is clear about wanting to use  `fseek()` et. al to view successive lines when opening and closing a file.

To open and close a file, and each time access and display a successive line, you must first know where each of the locations to be viewed are located within that file. Indeed, as you have tagged, [fseek()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm), (as well as [ftell()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ftell.htm)) can be used to do this. The following pseudo code steps illustrate one possibility:

```
//store file pointer locations of each line in file:
FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "r");
if(fp)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < l_cnt; i++)
    {
        pos[i] = ftell(fp);
        fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Then...

```
//alternately open and close file to view successive lines at stored positions
for(int i = 0; i < line_cnt; i++)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        fseek(fp, pos[i], 0);
        fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
        printf("line %d: %s\n", i, line);
        fclose(fp);
    }       
}
```

There is a more complete [source and run-time example here](https://replit.com/@ryyk/CheapTealEnterprise)